# How to have git differences of two files into a new file?

Tags: git

Any tool/technique/method for creating a new file from "git diff file1 file2" comment, so that the new file will only have the output of difference.

```
git diff file1 file2
```

Comment: Does `diff file1 file2` not work?

Comment: If you want to compare two different files from the working tree then you don't event need `git`. You can do it with any diff you you have installed on your computer. `diff` is one option if your OS is based on Unix (i.e. macOS or any Linux). You can redirect the output in a file (let's say `file3` by adding `> file3` at the end of the line.

Comment: @axiac Thanks, was pretty easy. I tried this with git also and it works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store the output of `git diff file1 file2` to another file, then you can achieve the same using the command `git diff file1 file2 > output_file`.
If you have some data in the output file and you want to append the new difference then you can use the command `git diff file1 file2 >> output_file`. This command will append the output of the `git diff file1 file2` command to the output_file file.

Answer (score 0):

In general, git is **NOT** used to get the differences *between 2 files*.

For that, you shall just use the `diff` command. And for the case you want, use `>` to send to output to a file, like:

```sh
diff file1 file2 >output_file
```

The `git diff` is used to get the differences between 2 git references (commits/branches/tags/...).

Sending the output to a file is actually a *patch*, which can then be applied to another file. This patch may contains the differences of more than 1 file.

If you want to restrict the differences of 1 file between 2 git references, then you would do:

```sh
git diff ref1..ref2 file >diffs_of_my_file_between_ref1_and_ref2.patch
```

This patch can again be used against 1 file to reproduce the changes. With `git apply` or simply the (non-git) `patch`. That is another story.

Beware: there are different diff formats. It is possible to specify this format with the options.